# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath swipe issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have custom UITableViewCell with some content on it. While I am trying to swipe (to show delete custom button with image) It's simply not working, or if I'll try to do that 10 times, so I could see the swipe delete button action.

my code is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MessagesCell

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Destructive, title: "       ") { value in

            // here some removing action
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "swipeToDelete")!)
        return [deleteAction]
    }
```

[image: my table cell]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in IIViewDeckController that blocked swipe with its PanGesture

Answer (score 0):

This code will help

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
return true
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's won't. Because I am using to delete another method editActionsForRowAtIndexPath, that can implement custom image for delete action button